# Building a quotation class in CSS

Tags: html, css

Good evening,

Lately I've been trying to get into HTML-CSS, just to familiarise myself with them both.

Now, I wanted to include a quotation in my HTML, one that is parsed hourly from my machine from a database of famous quotes. I've got everything up for reading the quotation through HTML, but I wanted to do something programming-y for the CSS styling of it.

My idea was:

1. Create a `.dailyquote{}` class in the CSS file.
2. Input the quote in the HTML as: 
   `<div class = "dailyquote"> Quote_text#Quote_Author</div>`
3. Have CSS print Quote_text until it reaches #, ignore the # then, for the remainder of the class content, do styling stuff to the author of the quote, such as `float:right` or a smaller font size. Minimal work in the HTML, everything done through the CSS.

The thing is, I don't know how to do any of that in CSS. As a programmer I reckon I'll need at least a looping structure and an if() condition.

Is something like that possible or am I mistaking CSS as a programming language? Maybe I'll have to work through the HTML?

Comment: This cannot be done with CSS, you will need Javascript.

Comment: if the quotes are coming from a database, you will need a server side programming language. CSS is merely for style rules and HTML is just a markup language. You could use JavaScript if the quotes were stored in an array or some other structure.

Comment: Why don't use two separate divs? one for the cite and one for the author?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That markup is rather wrong for a quotation. You should be using something like:

```
<blockquote>
<p>As my fellow HTML5 Doctor, Oli Studholme has showed, people seldom quote exactly 
– so sacrosanctity of the quoted text isn’t a useful ideal – and in print etc, 
citations almost always appear as part of the quotation – it’s highly conventional.</p>
<footer>
— <cite><a href="http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2013/on-citing-quotations-again/">Bruce Lawson</a></cite>
</footer>
</blockquote>
```

Source: [HTML 5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/)

> Is something like that possible

No.

> or am I mistaking CSS as a programming language?

You are.

You need to produce appropriate HTML for your content, and then use CSS to describe how you would like it to appear.

Generally speaking, the best place to transform that sort of data would be on the server (using a server side programming language).

Comment: Didn't know the `<cite>` element existed. And after looking at the [W3C wiki page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/cite) for it, you're technically using it incorrectly, because `a person is not a work` :). That seems nit-picky.

Comment: @ajp15243 — The wiki is out of date. See [the latest spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element).

Comment: @ajp15243 As I understand it, the spec has recently changed to allow such things - see [the HTML 5 Doctor link in Quentin's answer](http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/) :)

Comment: Well, looks like I won't be using the wiki as much. Which makes me sad, because it's way easier to read than the spec.

Comment: "My favorite movie is *star wars*." Well isn't that magical...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks like I'll have to go about this in some other way, then. Hopefully avoiding Javascript, ugh.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not really a programming language and doesn't have the concept of loops as such.

I'd change the HTML first: Use `<blockquote class="dailyquote">` instead of a `div` and put the author in a `<cite>` element. Then style accordingly. See http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/

```
<blockquote class="dailyquote">
    Duis sapien est, consequat nec ultrices quis, rhoncus id diam. Donec ac massa libero.
    <footer><cite>The Author</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

Then style as accordingly, e.g.

```
.dailyquote {
    color: red;
}
    .dailyquote cite {
        display: block;
        color: aqua;
    }
```

Comment: It was merely an example, giving me a chance to ask for the capabilities of CSS as a programming language. Thank you for your answer ;)